# SSRS expression display custom text

Tags: ssrs-tablix

Can i make field value hidden within Expression in SSRS because i don't want to display this integer value?
For instance: I placed text box where I created simple Expression:
="Click for Details" &  Fields!LocationId.Value

Fields!LocationId.Value is my specified parameter where I link Main report ID and Details report ID
I use Action within cell column to redirect to subreport based on unique LocationId.Value where user will click on the line with wording  "Click for Details".
When report runs I have in each cell :Click for Details3636
                                      Click for Details7239
and so on..
is mission impossible here??!!
Angelika

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work - you don't need to display the value used in the ACTION.

Comment: Seriously Hannover??!!! its ONLY matter in Action Tab as long as I mapped my Parameter to run Sub report :-). Thank you much! Angelika